# Error converting parameter in JSTL. (UTF-8)

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, jstl

I have a problem for accent display on my pages.

```
param.example = é

<c:out>${param['example']}</c:out>

return -> Ã©
```

My tomcat connector is UTF-8

projet config Spring 3, Java 7

```
<%@ tag description="page example" pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```